# Flick away a view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view that I want to be able to "flick" away (as seen in apps Jelly, Potluck and, Weotta). I have the view hooked up to pan gesture recognizer. The problem is it doesn't "flick" away (ie. if i flick it from the bottom of the screen it should go off the top of the screen without me having to drag it all the way to the top of the screen). Im assuming this would be somehow be done using UIKitDynamics but I'm not exactly sure how to implement it. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? (besides adding a gesture recognizer) We need to see your code or pseudocode so we can know where to help.

Comment: @random I've just done the pan gesture and have messed around with setting the frame of the view based off of its position

Comment: for a proper flick detection, you'd be better off writing your own gesture recognizer .. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW44 ..

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this.  The easiest is probably just to animate the view like this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"flick" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

yourView.frame = CGRectMake(yourView.frame.origin.x, -yourView.frame.size.height, yourView.frame.size.width, yourView.frame.size.height);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This just sets up an animation context for you, then you change the origin of your view to somewhere above the top of the screen.  Apple does the rest.  You can experiment with different animation curves and durations to see what looks best.  Look at [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut) for the values you can supply for the animation curve.

Comment: would this code go in the method for the pan gesture?

Comment: Yes - when you respond to the gesture, just trigger the animation and you're done.  You can try to get creative with it and allow the user to move the view up and down using touchesBegan/touchesMoved/touchesEnded, and only do the flick when they do a quick flick upwards, but this should at least get you started.